# MySQL DISTINCT on one column and not matching another

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

Having a nightmare trying to figure out how to pull some data from a table.

The table is set up:

```
PRODUCTS
---------------
ID - Primary
QuoteID Int
ProductCode VarChar(30)
```

I am trying to get all the `QuoteID`'s that don't have a Product code of `'01'`.

I tried:
`Select * from PRODUCTS group by QuoteID order by ProductCode asc`
but this came out with everything wrong as the `ProductCode asc` has values starting with 1.

I know swapping the column to `Int` would make life easier but the application relies on the value being `'01'` not `'1'` in places!

How can I modify my query to produce the desired result?

Comment: You don't have any WHERE clause. You need something like `WHERE ProductCode != '01'`

Comment: So the same `QuoteId` value can appear on multiple rows, accompanied by different `ProductCode` values?  Or else where does `DISTINCT` come into it?

Comment: And do you mean you want those `QuoteId`s that appear in any row with a product code different from `'01'`, or do you mean you want all `QuoteId`s in the table, *except* those that appear on any row with product code `'01'`?

Comment: A QuoteID will appear many times and each will have a different ProductCode. I am trying to find all the QuoteID's that do not have a ProductCode 01 stored against it but the same QuoteID will also have other ProductCodes stored that I do not need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select QuoteID from PRODUCTS where QuoteID NOT IN (select distinct QuoteID from PRODUCTS where ProductCode = '01')
```

explanation- the inner query will give you all the `QuoteID`'s that has `ProductCode = '01'`. the `not in` will give you the rest

Comment: This looks good but it killed phpMyAdmin trying to run it! I'll have another go tomorrow.

Comment: This was running for about 20 minutes before I gave up. Table has approx 450k rows, how long should I expect this to take to run.

Comment: You should check your indexes in that case, shouldnt run that long

Answer (score 1):

This get all of the quote ids from product where product code does not start with 01

```
Select QuoteID from PRODUCTS where ProductCode not like '01%'
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what he wants - this is not good as some QuoteID might have two entries - one with 01 and other without. Your query will return it which is wrong

Comment: So just add `DISTINCT` if necessary.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - distinct will not help (it will help if an entry appears twice and both don't match 01, not if one matchs and other dont)

Comment: @NirLevy, I see what you mean.  This is a matter of interpretation, however, and we'll need the OP to clarify what *he* means.

Comment: answered in the questions comments.